# Topological phase in Laguerre-Gaussian transverse mode

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics

Why is the topological phase in a [Laguerre-Gaussian transverse mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Laguerre-Gaussian_modes) is the sum of orbital angular momenta per photon, and why is it quantized?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I've edited your question to clean it up a bit. Please review it and fix any inaccuracies introduced by my edit.

Comment: Do you mean "topological phase", by referring to "geometric phase" or Berry phase? (sometimes phases also mean the phase of phase diagram. Then topological phase means "topological order".)

Comment: I mean, e^{il\phi}, where the topological phase is the "l"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take this question to mean:

1. Why does the [Laguerre-Gaussian (LG) modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Laguerre-Gaussian_modes) have an $e^{i\ell\phi}$ dependance on the azimuthal coordinate $\phi$?
2. Why is $\ell$ required to be an integer?

## Question 1

The LG modes are solutions to the paraxial wave equation in *cylindrical* coordinates. This means that we get solutions that reflect this symmetry. In particular the solutions should only trivially change if you make the change
$$\phi\to\phi+\Delta\phi.$$
If we define a rotation operator $R_{\Delta\phi}$ such that this operator acting on any function $f(\phi)$ gives
$$R_{\Delta\phi}f(\phi)\equiv f(\phi+\Delta\phi)$$
cylindrical symmetric solutions will be the eigenfunctions of $R_{\Delta\phi}$, i.e.
$$R_{\Delta\phi}f(\phi)=\lambda f(\phi),$$
where $\lambda$ is a constant.  The solution to this equation is of the form
$$f_\ell(\phi)\sim e^{i\ell\phi},$$
i.e.
$$R_{\Delta\phi}f_\ell(\phi)=e^{i\ell\Delta\phi}e^{i\ell\phi}=\lambda_\ell e^{i\ell\phi}.$$

Therefore cylindrically symmetric solutions such as the LG modes will be of the from
$$LG(r,\phi) = f(r)e^{i\ell\phi}.$$

## Question 2

The reason $\ell$ has to be an integer (i.e. quantized) is because $\phi$ is periodic. What this means is that $\phi$ and $\phi+2\pi$ are the exact same point, therefore all functions of $\phi$ must meet the requirement
$$f(\phi+2\pi)=f(\phi).$$
If our function is $e^{i\ell\phi}$, as we saw in part 1, then this means
$$e^{i\ell(\phi+2\pi)}=e^{i\ell\phi}\to e^{i\ell 2\pi} =1,$$
which is only true if $\ell$ is an integer.